# async pattern in a top-level worker method

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

We have some worker threads in a web role. It is created in the `OnStart` method

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWorkAsync(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Then the `DoWorkAsync` method will continue polling the queue and do some time consuming work. The actual work takes several minutes as it submits a query job and waits for the result to come back. Those functions are in `async` pattern. What's the right way to implement the top-level `DoWorkAsync` method? If I do the following, then it's kind of blocking here, and only one `PollingQueueAndWorkAsync()` is called.

```
public async void DoWorkAsync()
{
  while (_continue)
  {
    await PollingQueueAndWorkAsync();
  }
}
```

Or the following? It doesn't look right as it keeps running the method in a different thread.

```
public async void DoWorkAsync()
{
  while (_continue)
  {
    Task.Run(() => PollingQueueAndWorkAsync());
  }
}
```

I was trying the refactor the code to be "async all the way". But how should it end in the top-level worker method?

**[Update]**

After trying more, here is what I have:

```
public async void DoWorkAsync()
{
  while (_continue)
  {
    Task.Run(async () => await PollingQueueAndWorkAsync());
  }
}
```

The behavior is what I want, since new messages keep adding to the queue, this loop can process as many as messages in the queue. However after running this for a while, it throws our of memory exception. Is it because it creates too many continuations? So I should use SemaphoreSlim to throttle number of tasks?

Comment: If you want a good overall understanding of async/await, I would suggest starting here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally discourage code executing in ASP.NET that is not tied to a request. However, if it is carefully written as an independent worker (and it sounds like it is), then you can use the [`BackgroundTaskManager` type](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html) from my blog.

`BackgroundTaskManager` understands both synchronous and asynchronous tasks, and these tasks are registered with the ASP.NET runtime to minimize the chance that a recycle will terminate them unexpectedly. Also, the type exposes a `CancellationToken` called `BackgroundTaskManager.Shutdown` which your `PollingQueueAndWorkAsync` can use to detect when it should exit cleanly.

Comment: I have updated my post to add the another option. My question is the line  Task.Run(async () => await PollingQueueAndWorkAsync()); Does it mean it keeps running PollingQueueAndWorkAsync on a threadpool thread, when it runs to the underlying await, then this threadpool thread is returned back to the pool?

Comment: Yes, `Task.Run` will execute on a threadpool thread and when your method awaits the thread will be returned to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your polling threads like this:

```
public async void DoWorkAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => PollingQueueAndWorkAsync());
}
```

Then you should check for '_continue' within the threads themselves, so they can exit cleanly when the work is cancelled.

Comment: However I want the DoWorkAsync to keep running since a new message is adding to the queue all the time, and the DoWorkAsync need to continue processing them.